# Change image after window resize with Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, window, width, prepend

I've got some troubles with Jquery code. I'd like to change images on the page according to window width...

The code below makes almost what I want but there is one mistake - It prepends more than one image... It makes more and more clones after I re-size browser.

I would be grateful for any help you could give me..

Here is my code

```
(function ($) {
    var $window = $(window),
        $img2 = $('#img2');
    $img4 = $('#img4');

    function resize() {
        if ($window.width() < 750) {
            $img2.remove()
            $('.illu').prepend('<img id="img4" class="illu-img4 pulse_image" src="img/illu4.jpg"  width="100%"/>')
        } else if ($window.width() > 750) {
            $img4.remove()
            $('.illu').prepend('<img id="img2" class="illu-img2 pulse_image" src="img/illu2.jpg"  width="100%"/>')
        }
    }

    $window.resize(resize)
        .trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Note: Unless your code is at the bottom of the `body` element, using the jQuery IIFE syntax `(function($){})(jQuery);` is not as safe as using this shortcut DOM ready event handler: `jQuery(function($){YOUR CODE HERE});`

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle with sample HTML to ease our pain :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the images are in the same place, and you actually just want to replace them, you can just have one picture and change the source:

```
var $window = $(window),
    $img = $('#img');

function resize() {
    if ($window.width() < 750) {
        $img.attr('src', 'img/illu4.jpg');
    }
    else if ($window.width() > 750) {
        $img.attr('src', 'img/illu2.jpg');
    }
}
```

Another better option is to hide/show them as needed:

```
var $window = $(window),
    $img2 = $('#img2');
    $img4 = $('#img4');

function resize() {
    if ($window.width() < 750) {
        $img2.hide()
        $img4.show()
    } else if ($window.width() > 750) {
        $img2.show()
        $img4.hide()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, that was exactly what i need. Thanks everyone for your usefull responses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `$img2` & `$img4` selectors *inside* the resize event function:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $window = $(window);

    function resize() {
        var $img2 = $('#img2');
        var $img4 = $('#img4');
        if ($window.width() < 750) {
            $img2.remove()
            $('.illu').prepend('<img id="img4" class="illu-img4 pulse_image" src="img/illu4.jpg"  width="100%"/>')
        } else if ($window.width() > 750) {
            $img4.remove()
            $('.illu').prepend('<img id="img2" class="illu-img2 pulse_image" src="img/illu2.jpg"  width="100%"/>')
        }
    }

    $window.resize(resize)
        .trigger('resize');
});
```

When you remove them, your references are becoming broken and leaving any new images in the DOM on subsequent removes.

Note: I also switched the IIFE syntax `(function($){YOUR CODE HERE})(jQuery);` to the safer DOM ready shortcut format: `jQuery(function($){YOUR CODE HERE});`.

As `Banana` suggests, you are probably better off not creating and deleting, but hiding/showing/reusing the images, but this was just to answer the actual problem with your code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function resize() {
    if ($window.width() < 750) {
        $img2.remove()
        $img4 = $('<img id="img4" class="illu-img4 pulse_image" src="img/illu4.jpg"  width="100%"/>').prependTo('.illu');
    } else if ($window.width() > 750) {
        $img4.remove()
        $img2 = $('<img id="img2" class="illu-img2 pulse_image" src="img/illu2.jpg"  width="100%"/>').prependTo('.illu');
    }
}
```

You can try something like this. You are losing references while the body is resizing.